# Implementing List Creation in Flutter Web and Usage in Flutter(Dart) Mobile App

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a project using Flutter (Dart) , and I have a specific requirement. I need to allow list creation within the web app, and these lists should then be distributable to various accounts within my team. The crucial point is that list creation should be exclusive to the web app, while the mobile app is only meant for list usage.

Thank you for your guidance!

Currently, my plan is to implement this using a REST API, but I'm open to suggestions if there are better approaches. What would be the recommended way to handle list creation exclusively in the web app and enable list usage in the mobile app, ensuring a smooth integration with Flutter?

Comment: I typically use [Firebase Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) for creating, storing and sharing basic data. It's fast, cheap (includes a free tier), scaleable and cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`kIsWeb`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kIsWeb-constant.html) constant from the Flutter Foundation library.

```dart
if (kIsWeb) {
    // This is the web app, so we can allow creating lists.
} else {
    // This is not the web app, so we will only allow using lists.
}
```